# Azure app service python module import error on build

Tags: python, azure-webapps

I've been successfully deploying a Python Flask linux web app until last night. On my latest deployment the only change to my application was adding a new route (no new python modules). However the build gets the following error:

```
2019-03-02T04:46:08.721673278Z [2019-03-02 04:46:08 +0000] [34] [INFO] 
Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2019-03-02T04:46:08.731049340Z [2019-03-02 04:46:08 +0000] [34] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (34)
2019-03-02T04:46:08.731060340Z [2019-03-02 04:46:08 +0000] [34] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-03-02T04:46:08.740437601Z [2019-03-02 04:46:08 +0000] [37] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 37
2019-03-02T04:46:10.919571939Z [2019-03-02 04:46:10 +0000] [37] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-03-02T04:46:10.919591939Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-03-02T04:46:10.919596839Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-03-02T04:46:10.919610339Z     worker.init_process()
2019-03-02T04:46:10.919615539Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-03-02T04:46:10.919619939Z     self.load_wsgi()
2019-03-02T04:46:10.919623739Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-03-02T04:46:10.919627939Z     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-03-02T04:46:10.919631639Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-03-02T04:46:10.919635639Z     self.callable = self.load()
2019-03-02T04:46:10.919639439Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-03-02T04:46:10.919651139Z     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-03-02T04:46:10.919655538Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-03-02T04:46:10.919659638Z     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-03-02T04:46:10.919663338Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-03-02T04:46:10.919667338Z     __import__(module)
2019-03-02T04:46:10.919671038Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/application.py", line 3, in <module>
2019-03-02T04:46:10.919675238Z     import utils
2019-03-02T04:46:10.919678938Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/utils.py", line 2, in <module>
2019-03-02T04:46:10.919682938Z     import psycopg2
2019-03-02T04:46:10.919686738Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/__oryx_packages__/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
2019-03-02T04:46:10.919690638Z     from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
2019-03-02T04:46:10.919694838Z ImportError: libpq-bd31fe2b.so.5.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2019-03-02T04:46:10.920295036Z [2019-03-02 04:46:10 +0000] [37] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 37)
2019-03-02T04:46:11.013747652Z [2019-03-02 04:46:11 +0000] [34] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-03-02T04:46:11.013775151Z [2019-03-02 04:46:11 +0000] [34] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2019-03-02 04:46:12.038 ERROR - Container rich-py-api_0 for site rich-py-api has exited, failing site start
```

I'm using the free trial subscription. Since I don't control the installation of the python packages?

Comment: what do you mean "only change adding a new route"?

Comment: I suggest you comment your new route and try it again. If it works, then it's your new route and you must have an import that you only use in this route. There is the problem.

Comment: I commented the route out. Redeployed and the deploy worked. Then I uncommented the route and redeployed and the deploy also worked! So problem solved but still not sure why I got the import error above.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux appservice with Python is still in Preview and Microsoft is working out race-conditions that make deployment non-deterministic (see the issue tracker and PRs here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azureappservice/issues). I have had this identical issue plus several similar ones. I have had the impression that the very first deploy after creation of a new Linux appservice is more reliable than subsequent ones. I have therefore resorted to tearing down the Appservice, recreating it from scratch using the Azure CLI for automation, and then redeploying everything from scratch. Between creation and redeployment I also SSH into the container and install missing build dependencies for some of the Python packages I am using.

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev python-pip libpq5
```

Maybe it is safest at this time to use a bespoke Docker container instead.